# How do I catch all requests to an asp.net core app and send ton ONE page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We have moved an app from one server to another. This means that people that have old bookmarks/links will not be using the correct URL.

I'm therefore writing an app that will capture all requests and re-direct (with all controllers and parameters) to a new location after have displayed a message about the move for a few seconds.

I was thinking to store the new URL in a parameter on at the client side and then after some seconds redirect using JavaScript.
My problem is that all requests using controllers are not captured (the controllers don't exist in my new app, but will on the target app on the new server).

I.e.

https://oldServer => works ok

https://oldServer/SomePage/SomeAction/SomeId?someExtraValues=123 => IS NOT CAPTURED

```
//Using a middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // how to capture all requests and write new URL to a parameter ?
        await next(context);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not captured"? If you add a breakpoint to your middleware - it is not hit?

Comment: If I try an url with a controller ( like /SomePage/ in the example, the controller don't exist in my new app. But I would like it to be sent to the new server.
Sorry for not being too good in explaining in english.

Comment: So what is the goal for your app? To be a proxy to a new one? Or to just return something basically saying "redirect to new url"?

Comment: A bit of both I guess. Redirecting after a few seconds while showing a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use standard functionality like serving views you can try using so called catch-all routes (a bit about them in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#conventional-routing-order) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#multiple-conventional-routes)). For MVC app for example:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{*slug}",
    defaults: new {Controller="Home", Action="Index"});
```

Will catch all requests and serve `Home/Index` page. The same is supported in minimal APIs:

```cs
app.Map("/{*slug}", (HttpContext ctx) => ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
```

If you want to write directly to the response then you can just use  short-circuiting/terminal middleware (search [the middleware docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for the term). For example with [`Run` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#run-delegates):

```cs
app.Run(async ctx =>
{
    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: I used last code snippet. Works like a charm. thank you